# Creating user friendly URL through .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My url looks like -
`http://localhost/user_notes/public/index.php?id=1234`.
I want to be turn it into user friendly url like
`http://localhost/user_notes/public/1234`

My `.htaccess` file looks like -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/ /index.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

So now  when I use `http://localhost/user_notes/public/1234` location in browser it is giving me error (The requested URL was not found on this server).  So above htaccess file is not working as I expected.

My directory structure given below -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine ON
  RewriteBase user_notes/public/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me again. (+_+)

Comment: @Abhishekkamal, your welcome cheers and happy learning

Comment: If I use `#1234` (ID with the hash) then it is not giving me the ID by `echo $_GET['id']` (because regex is currently searching for numbers as ID). So what should be solution for this problem ?

Comment: @Abhishekkamal, oh ok, actually I had picked it up from your question :) not an issue try something like `RewriteRule ^([#]?[0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1` it should work fine cheers.

Comment: nope I am still not getting id with `$_GET['id']` I think because browsers has some default behaviour if he finds `#` in URL parameter

Comment: You can try in your browser. It will not work.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal, In my humble opinion, I would request you to open a new question with complete details so that we can check it there, let's keep base requirements of this question same, cheers :)

Comment: [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380405/unable-to-get-id-starting-with-from-url-php)