# Unable to get id starting with # from URL PHP

Tags: php, url, browser

I am trying to get the id from the URL.

URL : `http://localhost/user_notes/user.php?id=1234`

```
echo $_GET['id']; // outputs 1234
```

But If I use `#` at the start of the id then I am not getting id.

URL : `http://localhost/user_notes/user.php?id=#1234`

```
echo $_GET['id']; // outputs nothing
```

Comment: Please share your htaccess file in your question. Could you please do mention how this `#` is coming? Please do mention your url which you are hitting?

Comment: I explicitly included # in url. (Don't relate this question from previous one)

Comment: Ok since you have asked this in your previous question so I got confused, may be php experts could pitch in on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `#` as some value in url, you need to use url encoded version of `#` i.e `%23`, because `#` signifies an internal link to some section of the page. See https://www.yourhtmlsource.com/text/internallinks.html & https://way2tutorial.com/html/html_internal_links.php

If your url is `http://localhost/user_notes/user.php?id=%231234`, then you'll get `#` in

```php
echo $_GET['id'];
```